# Can I Push my code from VS Code to Salesforce Production

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx-cli

is there a way to push code from VS code to salesforce Production?

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not really recommended, you can do that by simply using deploy to org option in VS code. It will work as a regular deployment and run the tests automatically if required.

Another way to do that is by using [SFDX deploy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm) command and run this script if you are using source format or use metadata deploy command.

> $ sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app -u **production alias here**

Comment: could this work for Production as well?

Comment: Yes, it will work.